# Android ImageButton ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, android-imageview, android-imagebutton

How can make something like this?

[image]?

For my aplication I want some list of image button and if I've press one button I want to do something. I've really search on all google to find that and I've found some example but all of them are to complex and have so more details

Can anyone suggest me one tutorial or example about how to make a SIMPLE list of image button?

Comment: why you want use image button? onListItemClick of listview can do your porpose

Comment: I want exclusive image button because that is one requirement in my application :(, I need to use it and just it.

Comment: so you need use listview that each item is a ImageButton and you should set onClick for each ImageButton inside your custom adapter in getView method

Comment: yes, and after I click on one imageButton I will go in another activity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well a simple way to make a list of buttons is creating an adapter.   You would use this by doing something list `ButtonListAdapter buttonListAdapter = new ButtonListAdapter(context, List<"of whatever you send in">);.`  And then with the list `list.setAdapter(buttonListAdapter);`

```
class ButtonListAdapater  extends BaseAdapter
{
Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
List<"whatever you want to pass in such as images or textfiels or classes"> mDatas;

public ButtonListAdapater  (Context context, List<"whatever you want to pass in such as images or textfiels or classes"> results)
{
    mContext = context;
    mDatas = results;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
}

@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return mDatas.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position)
{
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position)
{
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ViewHolder holder;

    "whatever you want to pass in such as images or textfiels or classes" data = mDatas.get(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
                              "whatever layout you made, on click effect can be in layout on in code"
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.data_list_item, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.tvButton = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewButton);
        holder.lbButton = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Button);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.tvButton.setText(data.getData());

    "With the button here it depends on what you want to do and how, since its perfectly fine to put an onclicklistener here or in the layout"
    holder.llButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, OTherActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent)
        }
     });


    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder
{
    TextView tvButton;
    ImageButton lbButton;
}
```

And data_list_item layout xml can be something simple such as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >
  <ImageButton
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:id="@+id/R.id.Button/>

 </LinearLayout>
```